# how to make my bot do something forever until it is told to stop

Tags: loops, discord.js

My bot currently has this command "go" which I make it go into a while loop to just send back messages to the user, however it crashes because it will keep running regardless if the stuff inside of the loop is done yet. How can I make it so that the bot will not go over the loop again unless its already done with the current loop? And I want it to be able to be stopped by "stop" command

Answer (score 0):

You can create a variable to keep track of whether the while loop is executing or not, as demonstrated by the `ready` variable. You can also create a variable to signify if the while loop should stop, as demonstrated by the `stop` variable.

## Demonstration

[image: Discord start-stop demonstration]

## Code

```js
const prefix = '!';

let ready = true;
let stop = false;

client.on('message', message => {
  if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix)) return;
  const [command, ...args] = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(/\s+/g);

  switch (command) {
    case 'go':
      if (ready) {
        ready = false;
        while (!stop && /* your condition(s) */) {
          // do stuff
        }
        ready = true;
        stop = false;
      }
      break;
    case 'stop':
      if (ready === false) stop = true;
  }
});
```